# Gulp watch отказывается работать

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch

помогите пожалуйста.

```
var  gulp  =  require('gulp'),
     sass  =  require('gulp-sass');
     browserSync = require('browser-sync')

gulp.task('sass', function() {
    return gulp.src('src/sass/**/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('src/css'));
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({
        stream: true;
    }))
});

gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
    browserSync({
        server: {
            baseDir: 'src'
        }
    });
});

gulp.task('watch', gulp.parallel('browser-sync'), function() {
    gulp.watch('src/sass/**/*.scss', gulp.parallel('sass'));
    gulp.watch('src/js/**/*.js', browserSync.reload);
    gulp.watch('src/**/*.html', browserSyncreload);
});




gulp.task('default', gulp.parallel('sass', 'browser-sync', 'watch'));
```

Скрин ошибки: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPXgi.png

Comment: Лучше обходится без ссылок на внешние ресурсы. См. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Точку с запятой уберите перед точкой.

Comment: Спасибо))))))))